# Second order ODE with no $x$, problem with constants

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have an ODE

$1+(y')^2=2yy''$

for which I know the result must be 
$y(x)=\frac {(c_1^2+1)x^2}{4c_2}+c_1x+c_2$

Making substitution $v=f'(x)$ and solving the ODE

$ln|y|^2+c=ln|1+v^2|$, then

$\sqrt{c_1y-1}=v$

$v=\frac{dy}{dx}$

$dx=\frac {dy}{\sqrt{c_1y-1}}$

$x+c_2=\frac {-2}{c_1}\sqrt{c_1y-1}$

$\frac {c_1(x+c_2)}{-2}=\sqrt{c_1y-1}$

Ok, until now I think I didnt make any mistake, I think my mistake is in the next few steps with $c_1$ and $c_2$

$\frac {(c_1 x+c_1c_2)^2}{4}=c_1y-1$

$y=\frac {c_1(c_1 x+c_1c_2)^2 +4}{4c_1}$

Which is not the same answer i'm looking for (I expanded it and tried to play with it, but it can't be helped, it is not)

Comment: I can't open the picture, but your solution is true.

Comment: @MyGlasses edited, that's what wolfram throws

Comment: I could not match them. check the wolfram answer again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This differential equation of x-axis co-directrixed parabolas  have been  [recently derived](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2125705/equation-of-family-of-parabolas-having-fixed-directrix/2125819#2125819). Instead of integration we follow the easier way it is generated.. as it indirectly includes all the needed integration including what you already started.

For a second order DE we should have only two arbitrary constants and we have to eliminate one of the three constants  in:

$$ y=ax^2+bx +c \tag1 $$

Say we eliminate $c$.

Maximum/minimum (known) of point of parabola vertex is

$$ (x_m,y_m) = ( -b/2a , \, c- b^2/4a \,) \tag2$$

Definition of parabola locus with given initial radius of curvature using the above definition applicable for this differential equation we set distances to vertex and directrix equal.

$$ ( x+ (b/2a))^2  + (y- 1/(2a))^2 = y^2 \tag3$$

which simplifies to

$$ y=ax^2+bx + \frac{1+b^2}{4a} \tag4 $$

If you want the parabola in a form

$$ y= Ax^2 + c_1x + c_2  \tag5 $$

then compare coefficients in 4) and 5) to get:

$$ b= c_1,\quad A = \frac{1+c_1^2}{4c_2}. \tag6$$

EDIT2:

The quantity $ \dfrac{yy''}{ 1+(y')^2 }$ represents the *ratio of principal curvatures* if the curve is revolved about x-axis.

Let $ y' = \tan \phi $ be the substitution for integration then this ratio can be quite advantageously put into the form

$$ \dfrac{yy''}{ 1+(y')^2 }= \dfrac {d\,log( \cos \phi)}{d\,log( r)}=n, $$ 
then I had derived the following hopefully interesting cases.

- $n =-2$  profile of a Parachute
- $n=-1$ Sphere
- $ n=-\dfrac12 $  Cycloid
- $n= 0 \,$  Cone/Cylinder
- $n=+\dfrac12 $ Parabola  with directrix as x-axis
- $n=+1$ Catenary
- $n=+2 \,$ yet to find out; Are these Weingarten surfaces ?

Comment: This was indeed a curvature radius problem wth distances to vertex and directrix equal, so although you didn't answer what I asked, this is the correct way of solving this kind of problem.

Comment: EDIT2 addresses your question. They could form a class of such questions on integration.

Answer (score 1):

struggling: More than **one** hour for **one** error!

The error occur in last line with a surplus $c_1$:

$\frac {(c_1 x+c_1c_2)^2}{4}=c_1y-1$

$y=\frac {\color{red}{c_1}(c_1 x+c_1c_2)^2 +4}{4c_1}$

From main answer we see
$$y=\frac {(c_1 x+c_1c_2)^2 +4}{4c_1}$$
$$y=\frac {c_1}{4}x^2+\frac{c_1c_2}{2}x+\frac{c_1^2c_2^2+4}{4c_1}$$
$$y=\frac {c_1}{4}x^2+Dx+E$$
so
\begin{cases}
D=\dfrac{c_1c_2}{2}\\
E=\dfrac{c_1^2c_2^2+4}{4c_1}=\dfrac{4D^2+4}{4c_1}=\dfrac{D^2+1}{c_1}
\end{cases}
then
$$c_1=\dfrac{D^2+1}{E}$$
and answer is
$$y=\dfrac{D^2+1}{4E}x^2+Dx+E$$

Comment: Ok im dumb, thanks for that.